# Agregar multiple grupos para un parametro, argparse python3

Tags: python, python-3.9, argparse

Estoy intentando agregar múltiples grupos para un parámetro, quiero agregar a mi codigo:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group_exclude = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group_exclude.add_argument("--oneline", help="Enter the html command you want to convert", metavar='"<h1>example</h1>"')
group_exclude.add_argument("--file", help="Enter the html file you want to convert", metavar="/path/to/file")
parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", help="the name of the file in which the output will be saved")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

un argumento, en este caso "--file", donde file tomara como argumento el path de un archivo, ese archivo se leerá y se modificara, luego quiero que "--file" si o si vaya acompañado de otro parámetro que será "--output", output se encargara de guardar el contenido modificado a un archivo con el nombre que el usuario especifique con el parámetro "--output", pero el problema es que "--file" ya esta en el add_mutually_exclusive_group(), y no se como podría hacer que el parámetro "--file" vaya obligadamente con "--output" cuando se lo llame, pero que a la vez el parámetro "--file" sea opcional, como "--oneline" como ven en el código...

Estoy esperando algo parecido a esto:

```
python3 archivo.py --file=/home/user/Escritorio/file --output=archivo.xyz
```

Pero que output no sea un argumento opcional, sino un argumento obligatorio para "--file".

Comment: puedes pasar el agregarle el parametro `required=True`

Comment: Claro, pero ahí cuando el usuario quiera hacer un --oneline le saldría que el parámetro --ouput es obligatorio, cuando quiero que solo cuando el usuario haga el --file el parámetro --output sea obligatorio